# Access request after upload (ASP classic)

Tags: asp-classic

So, as I figured out, when I have a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and I upload a file, I can no longer access the object `request`. The following error is shown:

> Cannot use the generic Request collection after calling BinaryRead.

After checking some resources, I stumpled upon a statement, which says: "This is by design". Well, okay, not here to judge about design-decisions.

To give you a quick overview, let me walk you through the code:

```
if request("todo") = "add" then
    Set Form = New ASPForm 
    category = request("category")
    title = request("title")

    if len(Form("upload_file").FileName) > 0 then 
        filename = Form("upload_file").FileName 
        DestinationPath = Server.mapPath("personal/allrounder/dokumente/")
        Form.Files.Save DestinationPath 
    end if          
end if
```

Nothing too special here so far. Later however, when I try to access my `request` object, the error mentioned above occures:

```
<% if request("todo") = "new" then %> 
...
```

My question now, how to get rid of it or fix this. I don't want to open the upload in a popup if there is another way around. This is the only solution I could think off.

Perfectly would be an object, which checks `Form` and `request`. Alternatively maybe a check at the top of the file, which object I have to use?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a very popular ASP class/component that solved ASP file uploads. The site for that component has been taken down, but the code is mirrored here:

https://github.com/romuloalves/free-asp-upload

You can include this ASP page on your own page, and on your page instantiate the class to get access to the files in your form, but also to the form variables. Here is a piece of example code (`Upload.Form` accesses the form fields):

```
Dim uploadsDir : uploadsDir = server.mapPath(".")   ' whatever you want

Dim Upload, ks, fileKey, mailto
Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
    call Upload.Save(uploadsDir)
    ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    for each fileKey in ks
        Response.write(fileKey & " : " & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & "<br/>") 
    next
    mailto = Upload.form("mailTo")
Set Upload = Nothing
```

If you want to stick to your own implementation, you can probably figure out how to get to the form variables in a multipart/form-data encoded data stream by having a look at the code they use to do so.